# How can I arrange the elements of a list different in HTML + CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development (started yesterday actually) and I don't know how to do the following thing: I want to arrange the elements of the unordered list (which are 'inline-block'-ed) so as to have the text positioned at the "middle" of an image greater in pixels than the text.

For instance:

[From this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G81wP.png) I want to get similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ml71.png)

I have tried using "float" and "position: relative", but nothing really helped me.
How can i do this?

My code is the following for the "menu":

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Something</li>
            <li><img src="\assets\img\logo.png" class="logo"></img></li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>About</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the `CSS` code that you currently have.

Comment: Try text-align: center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FlexBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) which is new feature of CSS which helps create layouts and manage space between layout items in an easy way

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Something</li>
      <li><img src="\assets\img\logo.png" class="logo" /></li>
      <li>Contact</li>
      <li>About</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

[Fun game I used to learn FlexBox](http://flexboxfroggy.com/)

Although Flexbox works well in most modern browsers, you may need to add prefixes to support older browser versions.
[Browser Support for FlexBox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: Love the game you added, fun and handy!

Comment: This helped me a lot! And the game is extremely handy! Thank you very much!

Comment: flexbox isn't supported in old browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can set the line-height of the `<li>` items to the same height as your menu:

```
.navbar ul {
    height: 50px;
}
.navbar ul li {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m042aec0/

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox to position your elements.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .4s all;
}

li:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Something</li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100/100" class="logo" /></li>
      <li>Contact</li>
      <li>About</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
  font-family:"arial";
  font-size:12px;
}
ul,li{
  list-style:none;
}
.header{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}
.navbar{
  float:left;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

li {
  float:left;
    width           : auto;
    line-height     : 50px;
    height          : 50px;
    /* border          : 1px blue solid; */
    padding:0px 2px;
}
li span {
    display             : -moz-inline-box;  /* FF2 or lower */
    display             : inline-block;     /* FF3, Opera, Safari */
    line-height         : normal;
    vertical-align      : middle;    
}

li span     { *display  : inline;} /* haslayout for IE6/7 */
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><span>Home</span></li>
            <li><span>Something</span></li>
            <li><span><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="logo"></img></span></li>
            <li><span>Contact</span></li>
            <li><span>About</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Have a run at it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>HTMLiveCode</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   body {height: 100%; width: 100%; background: #000;}
   body .header {height: 100px; width: 100%;}
   body .header .navbar,
   body .header .navbar ul{height: 100%; width: 100%; display: flex;  padding: 0; margin:0; background: #fff; display: table;}
   body .header .navbar ul li {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 20%; text-align: center}
   body .header .navbar ul li img{vertical-align: middle;}
   
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="header">
      <div class="navbar">
          <ul>
              <li>Home</li>
              <li>Something</li>
              <li><img src="\assets\img\logo.png" class="logo"></img></li>
              <li>Contact</li>
              <li>About</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```